# Why does clicking a button inside a JQuery Dialog inside an updatepanel Posts the page insted of AsyncPostback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, updatepanel

Hi I have a Jquery Dialog inside a content page which I have declared  as follows  :

```
function showImageDialog(Id_Image) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //$("[id$='divImageDialog']").html($(Id_Image));
            $("[id$='divImageDialog']").dialog({
                title: ']',
                autoOpen: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).parent().children().children('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
                },
                open: function (type, data) {
                    $(this).parent().appendTo("form:first");
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $(this).dialog('destroy');
                },
                show: {
                    effect: "bounce",
                    duration: 500
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "fade",
                    duration: 500
                }
            });

        });
```

and I have an `updatepanel` inside a content page in which I have placed the following div :

```
<div class="divImageDialog" id="divImageDialog">
            <asp:DataList ID="DLImages" DataKeyField="Id" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table align="center">
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td align="center">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TFName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td align="center">
                                <img src='<%# "../Classes/Handlers/Handler.ashx?Type=1&Id=" + Eval("Id") %> ' />
                                <br />
                                <br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
            <div align="center">
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="lnkFirst" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/DL/btnFirst.png" CssClass="btnNav" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ToolTip="First" OnClick="lnkFirst_Click" />
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="lnkPrev" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/DL/btnPre.png" CssClass="btnNav" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ToolTip="Pre" OnClick="lnkPrev_Click" />
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="lnkNext" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/DL/btnNext.png" CssClass="btnNav" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ToolTip="Next" OnClick="lnkNext_Click" />
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="lnkLast" ImageUrl="~/Content/Images/DL/btnLast.png" CssClass="btnNav" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ToolTip="Last" OnClick="lnkLast_Click" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here Is the issue that when I click on each of the four navigation Imagebuttons Although the div is inside an `UpdatePanel` insted of an `AsyncPostBack` I get a `PostBack`  !

Answer (score 0):

You don't include the code for your UpdatePanel, so it's hard to guess what could be going wrong.  Perhaps you have a `asp:PostBackTrigger` element referencing your child controls?

Comment: There is no postbacktrigger !